# evaluate using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^0 z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\, dzdydx $$

I need to evaluate this using spherical coordinates.

My setup:

$$\int _{0}^2\int _{0}^{\pi/2} \int _{0}^{2\pi} z(\rho^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\, \rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta $$ can someone help me edit this last equation

Comment: I'm not sure what your last equation is.

Comment: I am being a bit nitpicky but would you mind fixing the latex and the dxdydz on your second integral? Also are you using math or physics spherical coordinates (i.e. what is the angle off if the Z axis, phi or theta?).

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  Recall that in the spherical coordinate system $(r,\theta,\phi)$, $z=r\cos(\theta)$, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and $dx\,dy\,dz\to r^2\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Then, we can write the integral $I$ as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^0 z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}\,dz\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\int_0^2 (r\cos(\theta))\,r^3\,r^2\,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=(2\pi)\left(\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\right)\left(\int_0^2 r^6\,dr\right)
\end{align}$$